# How to read quarterly data with R?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I'm trying to use Bayesian VAR, but I can't even get my data right properly. I get them from https://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/ but since a lot of them are quarterly data I have a problem to merge my variables since I'm unable to convert for example "2020-Q1" from char to date with as.Date.

I used the sub function to get 2020-1 for example and then tried `as.Date(, format="%Y-%q)` but it doesn't work, so I'm stuck.

```
textData <- "yearQuarter,Amount
2019-Q1,1000
2019-Q2,2000
2019-Q3,3000"

df <- read.csv(text=textData,header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

as.Date(df$yearQuarter,format="%Y-%q")
```

...which produces:

```
> as.Date(df$yearQuarter,format="%Y-%q")
[1] NA NA NA
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Hello Kire. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your post. You'll get more useful help more quickly if you include a small subset of data in your question.

Comment: Oops sorry, I will update it right when I get it together !

Comment: No problem. Jingxin answered your question, but in the future you'll get more useful help if you include a minimal reproducible example as part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)

d = yq("2020-Q1")
d
# [1] "2020-01-01"
year(d)
# [1] 2020
quarter(d)
# [1] 1
```